# max-height with flex: 1 and overflow

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

Given a `<div` that is a percentage height of its parent and that contains a contenteditable as a child, let the child fill all available vertical space and overflow: scroll when no more vertical space is remaining.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/devcon/pen/PoPyYEL)

Current behavior: overflow works as expected (scroll appears) with a maximum height set to a pixel int. However, with a percentage height, the contenteditable runs out of bounds.

[image]

edit: adding `display: flex` to `container` seems to help. I believe one must indeed [use flexbox all the way down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644245/5671022)

edit: containerB may seem superfluous. It's there to simulate a deeply nested contenteditable

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path, but I think you're overthinking it.

Get rid of the `.containerB` element, and set the flex property to `.container` instead, with the column direction.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 60%;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 4px;
  overflow: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fill {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.outer {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div class='fill' contentEditable>edit</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't clear on why that was there. I'm trying to simulate a situation in web app where the contentEditable is deeply nested.